# unmatched parenthesis in regex - Linux

Tags: regex, linux, perl

I want to replace (whole string)

```
    $(TOPDIR)/$(OSSCHEMASDIRNAME)
```

with

```
    /udir/makesh/$(OSSCHEMASDIRNAME)
```

in a [makefile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29)

I tried with

```
     perl -pi.bak -e "s/\$\(TOPDIR\)\/\$\(OSSCHEMASDIRNAME\)/\/udir\/makesh\/\$\(OSSCHEMASDIRNAME\)/g " makefile
```

but i am getting unmatched parentheses error

Comment: Why not just set `$(TOPDIR)` to the directory you want? That's what that variable is for.

Comment: @Mat : for this only I mentioned "whole string" . I dont want to disturb $(TOPDIR) or else all files will be generated under /udir/makesh/ leads to error.
$(TOPDIR) - root directory

Comment: It's sometimes easier to put your program in a file so you don't have to deal with shell metacharacter issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to "double" escape the dollar sign. Like this:

```
echo "\$(TOPDIR)/\$(OSSCHEMASDIRNAME)" | perl -p -e "s/\\$\(TOPDIR\)\/\\$\(OSSCHEMASDIRNAME\)/\/udir\/makesh\/\\$\(OSSCHEMASDIRNAME\)/g"
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, you don't need to use `/` for regular expressions.  They're just canonical.  You can use pretty much anything.  Thus your code can become (simplify away some `\`):

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s|\$\(TOPDIR\)/\$\(OSSCHEMASDIRNAME\)|/udir/makesh/\$\(OSSCHEMASDIRNAME\)|g " makefile
```

Now to actually address your issue, because you're using `"` instead of `'`, the shell attempts to figure out what `$\` means which is then replaced with (presumably) nothing.  So what you really want is:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e 's|\$\(TOPDIR\)/\$\(OSSCHEMASDIRNAME\)|/udir/makesh/\$\(OSSCHEMASDIRNAME\)|g' makefile
```

Comment: It's not working :( ... I am having hundreds of makefile , so i am using -p option .. Also you have used '|' symbol , is it possible to do multiple "find and replace" in single go ?

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt about escaping, you can simply use [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) or [`\Q ... \E`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters).

```
perl -pe 's#\Q$(TOPDIR)\E(?=/\Q$(OSSCHEMASDIRNAME)\E)#/udir/makesh#;'
```

Note the use of a look-ahead assertion to save us the trouble of repeating the trailing part in the substitution.

A `quotemeta` solution would be something like:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { $dir = quotemeta(q#$(TOPDIR)/$(OSSCHEMASDIRNAME)#); }
          s#$dir#/udir/makesh/$(OSSCHEMASDIRNAME)#;'
```

Of course, you don't *need* to use an actual one-liner. When the shell quoting is causing troubles, the simplest option of them all is to write a small source file for your script:

```
s#\Q$(TOPDIR)\E(?=/\Q$(OSSCHEMASDIRNAME)\E)#/udir/makesh#;
```

And run with:

```
perl -p source.pl inputfile
```